# Converter arquivo JSON em objeto - C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

Tenho o seguinte arquivo JSON:

```
{  
   "createdAt":"Apr 17, 2019 10:28:39",
   "id":"52329770-64e2-4759-9d3d-f2595973de4e",
   "items":[  
      {  
         "id":"82d2e4ab-da74-45df-a9ea-99cc257ead59",
         "name":"REFRIGERANTE KS",
         "quantity":1,
         "sku":"20",
         "unitOfMeasure":"un",
         "unitPrice":1440
      }
   ],
   "notes":"MESA",
   "paidAmount":1440,
   "payments":[  
      {  
         "accessKey":"0gyZYCs8kJIucvOCdc7dsNvOehcsRXTRX2iGNFUr7hdc1sUWx5",
         "amount":1440,
         "applicationName":"CieloLIO",
         "paymentFields":{  
            "clientName":"CieloLio",
            "upFrontAmount":"1000",
            "creditAdminTax":"500",
            "hasSignature":"true",
            "hasPrintedClientReceipt":"true",
            "primaryProductName":"DEBITO",
            "reference":"112121"
         },
         "primaryCode":"8",
         "secondaryCode":"208",
         "terminal":"mock_terminal"
      }
   ],
   "pendingAmount":0,
   "price":1440,
   "reference":"284807",
   "status":"PAID",
   "type":"PAYMENT",
   "updatedAt":"Apr 17, 2019 10:29:06"
}
```

Como faço para transformar isso em um objeto? Tenho que ter uma classe com todas essas propriedades? Qual função uso para transformar em um objeto?

Comment: Da uma procurada na web como instalar o nuget NewtonSoft.Json, ele faz isso! Você só vai precisar criar o model para armazenar esses valores e chamar uma função dele...

Comment: Eu faço a mesa recomendação do @Lodi. Use o [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: Você vai precisar de toda a informação ou apenas alguns dados?

Comment: Á principio não vou precisar de todas as informações. Consegui resolver usando o  NewtonSoft.Json, obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SOLUÇÃO

Primeiro tive que criar as classes para armazenar as informações do JSON. Encontrei um [site](http://json2csharp.com/) que faz todo esse trabalho para mim:

```
public class Item
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string unitOfMeasure { get; set; }
    public int unitPrice { get; set; }
}

public class PaymentFields
{
    public string clientName { get; set; }
    public string upFrontAmount { get; set; }
    public string creditAdminTax { get; set; }
    public string hasSignature { get; set; }
    public string hasPrintedClientReceipt { get; set; }
    public string primaryProductName { get; set; }
    public string reference { get; set; }
}

public class Payment
{
    public string accessKey { get; set; }
    public int amount { get; set; }
    public string applicationName { get; set; }
    public PaymentFields paymentFields { get; set; }
    public string primaryCode { get; set; }
    public string secondaryCode { get; set; }
    public string terminal { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string createdAt { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
    public int paidAmount { get; set; }
    public List<Payment> payments { get; set; }
    public int pendingAmount { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string updatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

---

Depois disso, é só usar o newtonsof para deserializar o objeto:

```
RootObject m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

---

E acessar as propriedades assim:

```
string status = m.Status;
```